# Images deleted from Gallery exists in my Application folder Android

Tags: android, android-gallery

I creating chatting application like WhatsApp. I'm storing my media files to folder created on sdcard XYXImages.

when I got to Gallery App and trying to delete these images, get deleted from gallery but exists on actual location i.e. in XYZImages/ .

When I tested this scenario with WhatsApp images deleted from actual folder.

please help me out thanks in advance...

Comment: Interesting issue. Have you closed the file you are writing to? You have to deallocate file resources in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. Actually this suggestion solve my another issue of creating thumb from video file... But this issue is not yet solved so please elaborate this in detail how can close file resource, when user trying to delete files from gallery gets delete.

Comment: YW. I've added it as an answer. Please mark as resolved if it helped..

Answer (score 0):

You need to close your files after writing to it. Android will not release the file lock until it is closed.

Comment: I am closing file streams but still getting problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to refresh the SD card try like this

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(
        Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```